# Dolphin Error when playing custom NSMBW levels

Tags: level-design, wii, emulation

I've been making custom NSMBW levels in Reggie! but whenever I try to play them, Dolphin gives three errors:

> Invalid read from 0x0000000d, PC = 0x8008e3fc

> Invalid read from 0x0000000d, PC = 0x8091fac0

> Invalid read from 0x0000000d, PC = 0x80924b70

I have the XML file properly set up, my levels are in the path /nsmb/Stage. I can get NewerSMBW to work, but not this. Another thing to note is I can import the levels that came from NSMBW, edit them, and then it occasionally works (stopped working recently), but when I make my own from scratch, it doesn't work. How can I fix this?

Edit: I sort of got it to work. The editing preexisting levels works when the path is /nsmb/Stages. However, I still cannot make levels from scratch. I’ll have to stick with this for now. Still, let me know if you have ideas or potential fixes.

(I'm not super sure this is where to post this question, if you know where I should, please let me know!)

Comment: If edited files are working but not newly created ones, have you checked if they have the same file encoding?

Comment: Edited files occasionally work. I use the same .arc file type that the original game uses, still to no avail.

Comment: I mean encoding used of content, not file type. You can use still .arc but encode it in UTF-8, UTF-16 or ANSI (typical ones) or something completely different. Usually when you edit a file, you keep the encoding from before. But a new file has the encoding of your editor

Comment: That's a good point. However, like I said before, editing the original game files occasionally works. Something I did not mention is that if I edit them too much, they may have worked before, but then they don't. Recently they seemed to have stopped working entirely.

Comment: Just checked, the file encoding types are the same. They're both binary.